# How to get Drawable from URL Async

Tags: android, url, kotlin, android-asynctask, android-drawable

I have the following function and AsyncTask:

```
fun downloadBitmapTask(url: String, postExecute: (Drawable) -> Unit) {
    DownloadBitmapTask(0, postExecute).execute(url)
}

class DownloadBitmapTask(private val triesCount: Int, private val postExecute: (Drawable) -> Unit) : AsyncTask<String, Unit, Drawable?>() {
    override fun doInBackground(vararg urls: String): Drawable? {
        val url = urls[0].replaceFirst(Regex("http[^s]"), "https:")
        Log.d("DownloadBitmapTask", "StartedDownload #$triesCount - $url")

        return try {
            val inputStream = URL(url).content as InputStream
            Drawable.createFromStream(inputStream, url)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d("DownloadBitmapTask", "${e.message} - $url")
            if(triesCount != 3) {
                Thread.sleep(1000)
                DownloadBitmapTask(triesCount + 1, postExecute ).execute(url)
            }
            null
        } finally {
            Log.d("DownloadBitmapTask", "finished - $url")
        }
    }

    override fun onPostExecute(result: Drawable?) {
        if(result == null)
            Log.d("DownloadBitmapTask", "RESULT NULL")
        result?.let{postExecute.invoke(it)}
    }
}
```

I would expect my output to look like this:

```
D/DownloadBitmapTask: StartedDownload #0 - https://www.hotflick.net/flicks/2007_Rush_Hour_3/tn300/007RH3_Oanh_Nguyen_001.jpg
D/DownloadBitmapTask: StartedDownload #0 - https://robocup-mediterranean-open.org/img/276511.png
D/DownloadBitmapTask: StartedDownload #0 - https://i.imgur.com/Te2KxTM.jpg
D/DownloadBitmapTask: StartedDownload #0 - https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/spongebob/images/f/f0/Smitty.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20160213220608
D/DownloadBitmapTask: StartedDownload #0 - https://www.dccomics.com/sites/default/files/styles/comics320x485/public/Char_Thumb_Batman_20190116_5c3fc4b40fae42.85141247.jpg?itok=_Or1JrO2
D/DownloadBitmapTask: finished - https://www.hotflick.net/flicks/2007_Rush_Hour_3/tn300/007RH3_Oanh_Nguyen_001.jpg
D/DownloadBitmapTask: finished - https://robocup-mediterranean-open.org/img/276511.png
D/DownloadBitmapTask: finished - https://i.imgur.com/Te2KxTM.jpg
D/DownloadBitmapTask: finished - https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/spongebob/images/f/f0/Smitty.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20160213220608
D/DownloadBitmapTask: finished - https://www.dccomics.com/sites/default/files/styles/comics320x485/public/Char_Thumb_Batman_20190116_5c3fc4b40fae42.85141247.jpg?itok=_Or1JrO2
```

But instead it looks like this:

```
D/DownloadBitmapTask: StartedDownload #0 - https://www.hotflick.net/flicks/2007_Rush_Hour_3/tn300/007RH3_Oanh_Nguyen_001.jpg
D/DownloadBitmapTask: finished - https://www.hotflick.net/flicks/2007_Rush_Hour_3/tn300/007RH3_Oanh_Nguyen_001.jpg
D/DownloadBitmapTask: StartedDownload #0 - https://robocup-mediterranean-open.org/img/276511.png
D/DownloadBitmapTask: finished - https://robocup-mediterranean-open.org/img/276511.png
D/DownloadBitmapTask: StartedDownload #0 - https://i.imgur.com/Te2KxTM.jpg
D/DownloadBitmapTask: finished - https://i.imgur.com/Te2KxTM.jpg
D/DownloadBitmapTask: StartedDownload #0 - https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/spongebob/images/f/f0/Smitty.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20160213220608
D/DownloadBitmapTask: finished - https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/spongebob/images/f/f0/Smitty.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20160213220608
D/DownloadBitmapTask: StartedDownload #0 - https://www.dccomics.com/sites/default/files/styles/comics320x485/public/Char_Thumb_Batman_20190116_5c3fc4b40fae42.85141247.jpg?itok=_Or1JrO2
D/DownloadBitmapTask: finished - https://www.dccomics.com/sites/default/files/styles/comics320x485/public/Char_Thumb_Batman_20190116_5c3fc4b40fae42.85141247.jpg?itok=_Or1JrO2
```

It seems to me like, for some reason, AsyncTasks are not really called Async here, but I don't understand why.
Note, he same happens when I use `executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, url)` instead of `execute(url)`.

Note also: this only happens when I use the Pixel 3a. When I use the Samsung Galaxy S7, it seems to work as expected.

Any idea as to why this happens and how to avoid it?

Comment: Why don't you use [`Glide`](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)?

Comment: You would surely have to use `executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, url)` instead of `execute(url)` for your expected result.

Comment: @ShreyGarg You mean as I have stated at the end of my question? ;)
Sadly this didn't work either

Comment: @NileshRathod Well, Im currently looking for alternatives like that, so thanks for the suggestion, but Id still like to know why what I did didn't work.

Comment: I did read that line in the question, but still mentioned so that you don't waste time trying to use `execute(url)`. I suspect the images are small and are getting downloaded rapidly before the next call. Try adding delay in `doInBackground()` for testing.